# Как выровнять вывод по левому краю в C++ без использования printf()

Tags: c++, вывод, стандартный-ввод-вывод

Используя метод cout.setw() или манипулятор setw() вывод выравнивается только по правому краю. Как выровнять его по левому краю без использования функции printf() языка Си?

Comment: std::left, std::right https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left